# How much lead abatement is necessary to reach safe levels?

Tags: safety, paint-removal, lead

I'd like to buy an older home (I live in CT), but with 2 little kids, I'm worried about lead. The confounding issue is that our real estate agent strongly discourages us from doing lead testing for houses we're interested in. The reasoning is that we already know it's there (e.g., a house built in 1938 that hasn't been renovated), but if we do the test, then we are legally required to acknowledge it (e.g., when selling the house, when doing renovations, if we want to foster children). I tried to research how much it would cost to completely remove lead in a home, and it looks like it could be 10-20k for windows, 20k for interior paint, 20k for exterior paint. That is it would cost us maybe 50k or more to be able to be able to say there's `No` lead. This "all or nothing" approach seems unpractical to me, and hopefully, unnecessary.

It seems like I should research on my own whether this is something I can shop for  in a house (i.e., should I exclude all houses built earlier than 1978) or fix before moving in (without doing testing). I don't want to buy a house, address the issues, discover that wasn't sufficient, but then be unable to afford fully fixing the issue.

I can't find any reference describing how much lead needs to be removed or encapsulated in order to reach a safe level. Everything I've seen seems to just conclude

1. there is no known safe threshold for lead ingestion, therefore
2. [less lead](https://www.epa.gov/lead/questions-and-answers-homeowners-and-renters-about-understanding-lead-inspections-risk#How) in the house is always better if you're worried, but
3. you don't want to wait for an elevated blood test to discover your abatement was inadequate (lead brain damage is irreversible).
4. dust level safety standards are set based on [practicality](https://www.regulations.gov/document?D=EPA-HQ-OPPT-2018-0166-0360), not exclusively effectiveness
5. an [abatement plan](https://eregulations.ct.gov/eRegsPortal/Browse/getDocument?guid=%7B40A1E155-0A00-C080-8712-3AC7DED89571%7D) will be created for me when necessary (but this isn't useful since I don't have a house yet)

Note, I'm not asking a health question here (I already found [something](https://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/138/1/e20161493) useful for that). What I'm looking for are more specific guidelines which explain what kind of abatements are necessary to achieve this recent [standard](https://www.epa.gov/newsreleases/epa-and-hud-announce-new-lead-dust-standards-protect-childrens-health) or better:

> EPA is lowering the dust-lead hazard standards from 40 micrograms of
>   lead per square foot (µg/ft2) to 10 µg/ft2 on floors and from 250
>   µg/ft2 to 100 µg/ft2 on window sills.

For example, here are some possible abatement steps:

1. It seems clear that [deteriorated paint](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/documents/parent_checklist3.pdf) must be repaired
2. But should I require no lead in windows/doors?
3. Remove lead from any chewable surfaces (e.g., window sills)
4. The actual encapsulating paint (not just painted over) everywhere?

Or does anyone know where could I look to get these kinds of answers?

Comment: Well paragraph 2 gives some limits and the link is easy to find : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_poisoning

Comment: I don't see any specifics through those links?

Comment: e.g., they don't seem to provide more info than what I've already summarized above and don't explain how much work is necessary to make a leaded house safe.

Comment: It seems to me that your real estate agent is more interested in selling a home than in your safety.  Yes, if you know that the home contains lead, you may be obligated to disclose that information.  But more importantly for this situation, knowing that it has lead may very well lead YOU to avoid buying this property and potentially costing the agent the sale.

It seems to me that you would want to know there is lead and either negotiate a fair compensation from the seller or move on.

Comment: In a competently maintained middle-class home with adequate supervision of children, there is very little risk of lead poisoning.  **The issue is government action**, which may be erratic.

Comment: @Harper Citation?

Comment: I agree with Harper keep the kids from chewing on the walls and trim and there is no risk. You can seal the walls and trim so lead doesn’t show on testing but let the kids chew on the walls and trim and they will be exposed

Comment: What you're saying is essentially consistent with what I'm reading everywhere... and it's not that I disbelieve it, but I'd like to know if there are any studies to back that up. I can't be the first person to want to know, e.g., some sort of study comparing home abatement level vs lead blood concentration.

Comment: If it is sealed the test will show negative for lead how can you get an exposure with out breaking the seal, want to prove it to yourself get some lead even a lead fishing weight paint it and then test now that you see it is negative drop the lead on the cement a few times (don’t chew on it lol) test again and where the paint flaked from dropping would be the same as chewing on it and you will get a positive. I am sure the studies are out there. But years back I had to take a lead abatement class (rip-off) sealing, and removal, if removing or sand blasting lots of other rules paint is cheap.

Comment: Don't forget about the plumbing. Even after we stopped using lead pipes, we were still using lead pipe solder until the 80s, and your kids will drink water even if they don't eat paint.

Answer (score 1):

So what will you do if, later on, either

(A) a third-party such as a case worker does a lead test and it comes out positive,

(B) you want to sell the house and the prospective buyer insists on a lead-free warranty

If you're going to muck with a house of that age , especially moving in with small kids, do the right thing and get it lead-free (or encapsulated).  Lead damage in people is irreversible.

Comment: According to current regulations, a case worker won't require abatement if there isn't visible pealing paint, but if we do a test, they'll make us abate. AFAIK, this is illogical. I don't think a buyer can insist on a lead-free warranty in this market, although they may pay less for a house where there's confirmed lead. We want a single family house in the city (where almost all have lead) but it doesn't make financial sense to remove all the lead (according to estimates from homeadvisor.com). It seems we must compromise, so I want to know how much flexibility I have on safety requirements.

Comment: Well, that's my understanding of the regulations anyway.